# How to make a proper progress dialog for a thread

Tags: java, swing, progress

I have a small dialog with a progress bar. The dialog is opened from a separate thread and gets, as the parent, the main window. 
The problem is, when I click on the main window, it comes to the front, but not the child dialog.

The child dialog can not be modal, otherwise the thread wouldn't continue. So how can I properly parent the windows, so that, when I click on the main window, the dialog is shown.
Maybe the dialog should be opened from the main window? But then the main window would be blocked.

What I would have is, to block the main window operation until the thread is finished, the main window should still be responsive, so I can stop the thread, and the thread (or somebody) should update the progress dialog while running.

Any advice how to set this up?

Comment: *"The child dialog can not be modal, otherwise the thread wouldn't continue."*   Of course it would, so long as 'the thread' was not the EDT.  Is this Swing?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - what's EDT?

Comment: @david99world EDT = Event Dispatcher Thread

Comment: I just tried to set it to modal, but as expected the thread got stuck. :) How do I know who the EDT is? The one who contruscts the dialog?

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: _The dialog is opened from a separate thread_ Very bad idea. All Swing code must be called from the EDT. _The problem is, when I click on the main window, it comes to the front, but not the child dialog._ Most likely you failed providing the parent window to the child dialog (use `new JDialog(parentFrame)`)--> this will bring the dialog above the main window when clicking the main window.

Comment: Possible [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928213/using-swingworker-to-add-a-progress-bar-in-a-gui/14928329#14928329), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020949/jprogressbar-isnt-progressing/12021971#12021971), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201102/progress-bar-not-working/14206402#14206402), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199091/progress-bar-java/15199220#15199220)

Comment: And from the sound a of it, you might benefit from a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Thanks, that looks very promising! :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer So finally I found a solution here that works, and your comments got me thinking on hwo to properly do this! A very annoying inconvenience solved. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925656/swing-worker-modal-dialog-wont-close